# How to convert into Title Case in mysql query builder in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, mysql-workbench

I just want to ask how to convert the data I'm getting from database in Title case, its giving me an error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use

I'm just using UCASE and LEFT, here's my code,

```
DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT " " ,
    CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(ru.firstname, " ", ru.lastname, 1)))) AS relates_to')
```

The output I want for example is "user name" into "User Name", oh and I'm using the latest MySQL Workbench just to inform you

Hope you can help me and notice me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What exactly your goal why you need to make it Title Case in  the Query??

Comment: Fix formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LEFT` function only takes two parameters, so this alone would cause your current code to fail.  You may try reworking it as follows:

```
DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ' ' , LEFT(UCASE(CONCAT(ru.firstname, ' ', ru.lastname)), 1)) AS relates_to")
```

I don't know what your logic is exactly trying to achieve, but the above should at least run without error.

Comment: thank you sir, didn't solve my problem but atleast I'm not getting the error anymore

Comment: If you can clearly articulate your logic, using sample input data, plus the output you want to see, maybe I can help with that too.  Absent this, the above is the most I can do.